# Code Parallelisation using MPI in C

Tags: c, parallel-processing

I am performing code parallelization using MPI to evaluate the cost function.

I dividing population for 50,000 points among 8 processors.

I am trying to parallelize the following code but struggling with it:

```
//mpiWorldSize is number of processors
//=====================================

 for (int k=1; k< mpiWorldSize; k++)
{
   MPI_Send(params[1][mpiWorldRank*over+k],7,MPI_INT, 0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

// evaluate all the new costs
//=========================

for (int j=1; j<mpiWorldSize;j++)
{
   MPI_Recv( params[1][mpiWorldRank*over+k],7,MPI_INT,j,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
}

// memory allocation
//=========================

SecNewCostValues = (float*) malloc(noOfDataPerProcessor/bufferLength);

//loop throw nuber of data per proc

for ( i = 0; i < over; i++ )
{   
  if(mpiWorldRank != 0)
    {
       SecNewCostValues[i] = cost( params[1][mpiWorldRank*noOfDataPerPreocessor+i] ); 
        newCostValues[over] = cost( params[1][i] ); //change the i part to rank*nodpp+i
        printf("hello from rank %d: %s\n", mpiWorldRank ,procName );
    }
 }
```

I can't send and receive the data from different processors except 0.

I will appreciate any help.

thanks

Comment: i suggest you add `mpi` tag as well

Answer (score 1):

MPI uses S*ingle Program Multiple Data* message passing programming model, that is all MPI processes execute the same program and you need to use conditionally to decide which process will execute which part of the code . The overall structure of your code could be as follows (assuming master with rank 0 distributes work and worker receive work).

```
if (myrank == 0) { // master
  for (int k = 1; k < mpiWorldSize; k++) { // send a chunk to each worker
    MPI_Send(...);
  }
}
else { // worker
  MPI_Recv(...); // receive work
}
```

Analogously master would collect work. Check out documentation on `MPI_Scatter()` and `MPI_Gather()` collective communication functions which seem relevant.